# Array containing function variables

Tags: javascript, node.js

*Wasn't sure how to title what I'm looking for properly so I'll try and explain*

I have a function

```
function cat(name, job, height){
 console.log(name);
}
```

and I'm trying to randomise the 3 variables using the following code

```
let Array = ['jim, cook, 5','nick, dog, 2'];
const RandomMake = Math.floor(Math.random() * Array.length);
let Random = Array[RandomMake];
```

so say `Random` output's `jim, cook, 5` i'd like to use those variables within my function.

```
cat(Random);
```

Obviously I'm not making a cat generator but it explains what I need. I can't randomise each individual value it must be the group of items (name job height). I'm not sure if this is possible or if i'm just forgetting about a function that will allow me to do this. But it's definitely puzzled me... Thanks in advance for the help :) Always learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split the randomly selected string by `,` and spread the result into the call of `cat`:

```js
function cat(name, job, height){
 console.log(name);
}
const arr = ['jim, cook, 5','nick, dog, 2'];
const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
const randomItem = arr[randomIndex];
cat(...randomItem.split(', '));
```

But, if possible, it would make a bit better organizational sense to have array of objects rather than an array of strings:

```js
function cat({ name, job, height }){
 console.log(name);
}
const arr = [{
  name: 'jim',
  job: 'cook',
  height: 5
}, {
  name: 'nick',
  job: 'dog',
  height: 2,
}];
const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
const randomItem = arr[randomIndex];
cat(randomItem);
```

Also, you should avoid declaring a variable named `Array` - this will shadow the global `window.Array`, which could easily cause problems. Best to give the variable a different name, like `arr`.

Comment: Yeah, awesome thanks! I'm working with an automated api so it's proven easier just to paste in strings instead of making an array of objects. And yea I should've picked up on that before posting haha that was only an example :) I'll Accept in 5 min (need to wait for the cool down)

Comment: Sure, if you have to write out a whole lot of things, I can understand using strings. If you need to go that route, you could make things even easier (syntactically) by using a multi-line template literal that you then split by newlines to create the random array. It'll be a bit less mistake-prone than something like `['jim, cook, 5','nick, dog, 2']` with a lot of items.